# Traduction de « require » : « requérir » ou « exiger » ?

Tags: traduction, anglais, synonymes, science

> Invert R(T) to find the temperature T as a function of R. Require that
> T(R) be an ever-increasing function of R between the normal ice point
> and the melting point of sulfur.
>
> Inverser R(T) pour trouver la température T en fonction de R. Exigez/Requérez que T(R) soit une fonction toujours croissante de R entre le point de glace normal et le point de fusion du soufre.

A/ Quel verbe rend le sens du verbe *require* dans ce contexte ?

B/ Quand les deux verbes français peuvent-ils être employés de façon interchangeable ?

Pour plus de clarté voici l'énoncé complet original.

[image]

Comment: Je trouve l'impératif de l'original étrange. S'agit-il d'un énoncé d'exercice ? Dans ce cas 'Invert' est logique, mais à qui s'adresse 'require' ? Si c'est parce qu'il existe _a priori_ des solutions multiples, je dirais peut-être 'on imposera que T soit (strictement ?) croissante' (je n'avais jamais vu 'ever-increasing' avant). Ou si c'est du bon sens, 'on s'assurera que [...]' ou 'on vérifiera que [...]'.

Comment: @MathieuBouville Merci pour le retour. Je viens de modifier la question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si le texte anglais indique un prérequis (mais il aurait plutôt été écrit *Requires that*) :

> Inverser R(T) pour trouver la température T en fonction de R. **Impose** que T(R) soit une fonction strictement croissante de R entre les points de fusion de la glace et du soufre.

S'il s'agit d'une instruction (impératif), alors, comme l'a suggéré Stéphane :

> Inverser R(T) pour trouver la température T en fonction de R. **Faire en sorte que** que T(R) soit une fonction strictement croissante de R entre les points de fusion de la glace et du soufre.

Comment: *Faire en sorte que* me semble bien plus naturel. « Impose(r?) », je n'aurais même pas compris.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Tu as probablement raison car il n'y a pas de *s* en anglais.

Answer (score 2):

J'utiliserais simplement le verbe « choisir » ;

- choisir pour solution la fonction croissante

Il y en a deux, l'une croissante, l'autre décroissante. L'anglais « require » n'est peut être pas de la meilleure inspiration.

Answer (score 0):

Ayant fait pas mal de problèmes de ce genre, la formule qui me vient à l'esprit n'est pas une traduction mot-à-mot :

> Vous ferez l'hypothèse que / On fera l'hypothèse que...
>
> Vous accepterez que / On acceptera que...
>
> Vous poserez que / On posera que...
>
> Vous postulerez que / On postulera que...

Answer (score 0):

**requérir** et **exiger** ont le même sens. Simplement, **requérir** est un peu ancien, un peu *passé de mode*, aujourd'hui on utilisera plutôt le verbe **nécessiter**, qui est une façon polie de dire **exiger**, dans ce contexte en particulier (sourire).